# JNI with native method malloc() causing crash on Cygwin

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, cygwin, malloc

I have a custom DLL in C with one native function as simple as this:

```
void Java_main_Main_testMalloc(JNIEnv *env){
    char *c = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
}
```

Inside Java:

```
package main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.loadLibrary("libJNI_test1");
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        testMalloc();
    }

    native void testMalloc();
}


Main:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000018011ae47, pid=8604, tid=5464
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xdae47]
```

This is stripped version, of course. But i'm sure it crashes on malloc() due to all the tests i've made. Just comment out malloc, compile the DLL and it will be fine. Crashes with Fatal error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005). Sometimes it runs fine, other times it will hang at the point of where Java calls the native method... What i do wrong? How can i allocate native memory that i will temporary use as buffer or w/e?

Comment: That's not the exact method call that's be generated by `javah` is it?  You should have a `jobject` passed also.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , true, according to JNI, i must have JNIEnv and jobject by default for all. Regardless, issue still persists. I tried to do absolutely the same with a c++ compiler, with the exact difference of having malloc() replaced with new char[5] . And it works, no problems at all.

Comment: So you don't correctly define your method, and you're wondering why it doesn't work right?

Comment: @AndrewHenle , perhaps i didn't clarified. It doesn't work no matter how i define the method - with or without jobject - the effect is still the same. It's malloc()'s fault, because when i switched to c++ and had everything the same, but change malloc() for new char[5], it works flawlessly. But i need to be in C land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNI declarations must have *exactly* the right parameters, including parameters that aren't used, and the function declaration must include the macros JNIEXPORT and JNICALL from jni.h. Without these, it's possible that the function won't return the stack to the correct state when it exits, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Change the function declaration to say:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_main_Main_testMalloc(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
     char *c = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
 }
```

and then see what you get.

Comment: Same effect. Edited OP to include some details.

Comment: Are you able to call other functions within the C library?

Comment: Tried some arbitrary ones: rand() works, printf() not working, strtod() not workding, sin() works, calloc() not working, fopen() not working. :(

Comment: Interesting. If this is not a problem with the calling convention (because JNICALL etc. didn't help) then this must be a problem with your cygwin installation. Do you have to use cygwin? I have had all sorts of trouble with it and can suggest mingw as an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough, i will try with mingw after i post a bug report. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes there's more than one cygwin1.dll on the system, and if you are compiling against one but Java is using another, you'll get weird behaviour. That could explain why the C library functions, e.g. printf, don't work, but math library functions, e.g. sin, are working

Comment: Yep, it works with mingw... Sucks though :( . Thanks!